# Airwatch Catalog and Airwatch Tunnen URL Scheme?

Tags: android, ios, url-scheme, tunnel, airwatch

My company is using AirWatch as an MDM and I need to develop an app on both Android and iOS. This has been achieved using react-native

My problem is that I can't find any information on the URL schemes for the AirWatch Tunnel. My use case is that if the user does not have the tunnel installed then i would like to redirect him/her to the app in the app catalog.

Does anyone know where I can get the url scheme for the airwatch tunnel?

Answer (score 1):

In my company we periodically push the tunnel app from the AirWatch console, and inside the apps we check the result of the HTTP connection to the internal url.
If there's an error we show a message suggesting to check internet connection and availability of the tunnel app.

I know it's a workaround, but I think the tunnel app doesn't provide a URL scheme. For Android you could check the list of installed app and search for a specific app bundle, but on iOS this won't work.